# Running total in two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider two tables: invoices and payments. The invoices table contains records of invoices raised, and the payments table contains records of payments received.

invoices

| id | date | cname | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-12-12 | cname1 | 10000 |
| 2 | 2021-12-13 | cname2 | 5000 |
| 3 | 2022-01-15 | cname1 | 7000 |
| 4 | 2022-01-16 | cname2 | 1000 |

payments

| id | date | cname | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-05 | cname1 | 5000 |
| 2 | 2022-01-07 | cname2 | 5000 |
| 3 | 2022-02-05 | cname1 | 10000 |
| 4 | 2022-02-06 | cname2 | 1000 |

CALCULATE RUNNING BALANCE

Q) Extend the SQL query to do invoice / payment matching as follows (as of 28/2/2022)

matching

| date | document_id | cname | amount | due |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-12-12 00:00:00 | 1 | cname1 | 10000 | 10000 |
| 2022-01-05 00:00:00 | 1 | cname1 | -5000 | 5000 |
| 2022-01-15 00:00:00 | 3 | cname1 | 7000 | 12000 |
| 2022-02-05 00:00:00 | 3 | cname1 | -10000 | 2000 |
| 2021-12-13 00:00:00 | 2 | cname2 | 5000 | 5000 |
| 2022-01-07 00:00:00 | 2 | cname2 | -5000 | 0 |
| 2022-01-16 00:00:00 | 4 | cname2 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 2022-02-06 00:00:00 | 4 | cname2 | -1000 | 0 |

Answer (score 0):

You can union both tables considering the second one with negative amount, and then a simple running total will produce the result you want. For example:

```
select
  date,
  id as document_id,
  cname,
  amount,
  sum(amount) over(partition by id order by date) as due  
from (
  select * from invoices
  union all select id, date cname, -amount from payments
) x
order by cname, date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `date`,
documentId,
cname,amount,
due FROM (SELECT `date`,
documentId,
cname, 
amount,
(CASE WHEN @running_customer=''  THEN @running_balance:=amount
 WHEN @running_customer=cname THEN @running_balance:=@running_balance+amount ELSE @running_balance:=amount END) due,
 @running_customer:=cname
 FROM (SELECT `date`, id AS documentId,cname, amount FROM `invoices`i
UNION ALL 
SELECT `date`, id AS documentId,cname, amount*-1 AS actionType FROM `payments` p) final
   JOIN (SELECT @running_customer:='') rc   
JOIN (SELECT @running_balance:=0) rb
ORDER BY cname, `date`) finalResult
```

You need to be using assignment operator for these kind of problems.